# EIP definitions of SHOULD, MUST, OPTIONAL

Tags: eip

I'm reading through the [EIP20 specificaiton](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md) and have come across the terms `SHOULD`, `MUST`, and `OPTIONAL`.

OPTIONAL seems straightforward, but what is the difference between SHOULD and MUST?

Nothing is mentioned in [EIP1 - EIP Purpose and Guidelines](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1.md).

Where do I find definitions of these terms?

Comment: Regarding inclusion into EIP1, I raised [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/736).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an industry standard (as far as RFCs can be considered standards... ), defined in 1997 in [RFC-2119: Key words for use in RFCs to Indicate Requirement Levels](http://www.rfc-base.org/rfc-2119.html).

From the abstract of this document:

> In many standards track documents several words are used to signify
>   the requirements in the specification.  These words are often
>   capitalized.  This document defines these words as they should be
>   interpreted in IETF documents.  Authors who follow these guidelines
>   should incorporate this phrase near the beginning of their document:
>
> ```
>   The key words "MUST", "MUST NOT", "REQUIRED", "SHALL", "SHALL
>   NOT", "SHOULD", "SHOULD NOT", "RECOMMENDED",  "MAY", and
>   "OPTIONAL" in this document are to be interpreted as described in
>   RFC 2119.
> ```

It's possible further keywords were added to later RFCs, but I always refer to 2119.